# Illumination normalization in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, normalization, aforge, emgucv

I want to detect eyelid blinks in a video stream in C#, I am using a method mentioned in [this](http://www.nims.re.kr/include/file_down.php?dfile_name=20105007215049.pdf&dfile_folder=TRE) paper.

**Excerpt from the paper:**

> Therefore, a faster algorithm for solving this illumination variation problem is proposed, as follows: after the RGB input image is converted to an L*a*b* image, an illuminative component is acquired by applying a 31×31 median filter to the L image, as shown in Fig. 6(b). By applying median filtering, the illuminative component of the input image, excluding the detailed formation of the eye regions, can be approximated, as shown in Fig. 6(b).
>
> Here, the optimal size of the median filter is empirically determined experimentally in terms of the eye detection accuracy. Then,the inverted illuminative image is obtained, as shown in Fig. 6(c).
>   The influence of the illuminative variation is compensated for by adding the inverted image to the original L image. Consequently, an illumination-compensated RGB image is acquired, as shown in Fig. 6(d).
>
> Fig. 7 shows the result of the binarized eye image using the proposed illumination normalization. In this binarization procedure, the threshold is automatically determined on the basis of the study byGonzalez and Woods (2002). The binarization result shown in
>   Fig. 7(b) is much better than those shown in Fig. 5(b) and (c).
>
> Fig. 8 shows other examples of binarized eye images after illumination normalization

**Edit:**

[Fig.5 http://imageshack.com/a/img837/2086/w665.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img837/2086/w665.jpg)

[Fig.6 http://imageshack.com/a/img440/6157/kmo6.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img440/6157/kmo6.jpg)

[Fig.7 http://imageshack.com/a/img7/5584/rloq.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img7/5584/rloq.jpg)

For color space conversion I am using code from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19045/Manipulating-colors-in-NET-Part-1#xyz2) link.

**My code is:**

```
void RGBtoXYZ(Bitmap bm, int row, int col, CIEXYZ[,] xyz)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            xyz[i, j] = ColorSpaceHelper.RGBtoXYZ(bm.GetPixel(j, i).R, bm.GetPixel(j, i).G, bm.GetPixel(j, i).B);
        }
    }
}

void XYZtoLAB(CIEXYZ[,] xyz, int row, int col, CIELab[,] lab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            lab[i, j] = ColorSpaceHelper.XYZtoLab(xyz[i, j]);
        }
    }
}

void LABtoXYZ(CIEXYZ[,] xyz, int row, int col, CIELab[,] lab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            xyz[i, j] = ColorSpaceHelper.LabtoXYZ(lab[i, j]);
        }
    }
}

void XYZtoRGB(Bitmap bm, int row, int col, CIEXYZ[,] xyz)
{
    Devcorp.Controls.Design.RGB rgb;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            rgb = ColorSpaceHelper.XYZtoRGB(xyz[i, j]);
            bm.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(rgb.Red, rgb.Green, rgb.Blue));
        }
    }
}
void MedianLabImage(CIELab[,] lab, int row, int col, int filter_width)
{
    double value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            value = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < filter_width; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < filter_width; c++)
                {
                    int image_r = Math.Min(Math.Max(i + r, 0), row - 1);
                    int image_c = Math.Min(Math.Max(j + c, 0), col - 1);

                    value += lab[image_r, image_c].L;
                }
            }

            value /= (filter_width * filter_width - 1);
            lab[i, j].L = value;
        }
    }
}
void MyFunction()
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\Untitled.bmp");//@"C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\EyeBmp.bmp");


    int imgRow, imgCol;
    imgRow = img.Height;
    imgCol = img.Width;


    CIEXYZ[,] xyzImage = new CIEXYZ[imgRow, imgCol];
    CIELab[,] labImage = new CIELab[imgRow, imgCol];

    RGBtoXYZ(img, imgRow, imgCol, xyzImage);
    XYZtoLAB(xyzImage, imgRow, imgCol, labImage);

    MedianLabImage(labImage, imgRow, imgCol, 9);//My confusion starts after this


    LABtoXYZ(xyzImage, imgRow, imgCol, labImage);
    XYZtoRGB(img, imgRow, imgCol, xyzImage);
}
```

Can anyone please confirm that I am doing this correctly? Also my main question is what do the authors mean by

> "Then, the inverted illuminative image is obtained, as shown inFig. 6(c)."

and

> "The influence of the illuminative variation is compensated for by adding the inverted image to the original L image. Consequently, an illumination-compensated RGB image is acquired, as shown in Fig. 6(d)"

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stephan Bauer-Can you please tell me why Stackoverflow rejects my edit when I add pictures?